# DatePicker Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, html5, popup

I have two text field:

One normal text field that accepts numbers.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!FinancialAssCont.Down_Payment__c}" styleClass="form-control downpaymentAmount" onblur="checkValidQuantity(event);" />
```

Another field is a date Type field and on focus it opens datePicker control :

```
<apex:inputField value="{!FinancialAssCont.Initial_Date__c}" styleClass="form-control calendar_icon inital-date cal-text" onblur="copyInitialDate(this);" />
```

This is the algo of onblur event:

```
function checkValidQuantity(evt){
   if(inValidQuantity){
       showJqueryPopup();
   }

}
```

Issue on IE11:
When I enter the Invalid Quantity, I get a jquery popup. But the datefield also receives the focus which opens the datePicker. So i have at a time popup as well as datPicker open. I want to hide the datePicker when popup is open.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like common problem :

Can you try below :

Include the  Javascript snippet mentioned below after the page tag.

```
<apex:page>
<script>function setFocusOnLoad() {}</script>
<!-- further content -->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have an update on this issue:

I fixed it by doing a funny trick.

Scenario: Enter wrong value in number field textbox - which is field1. Check validation on blur event .Error Message popup ones. But datePicker also shows up.

My Fix:
I added onfoucs event to numeric field and called a function hideCalander.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!FinancialAssCont.Down_Payment__c}" styleClass="form-control downpaymentAmount" onblur="checkValidQuantity(event);" onfocus="hideCalander();" />

function hideCalander(){
     jQuery('#datePicker').css("display","none");
}
```

Now I modified checkValidQuantity function:

```
function checkValidQuantity(evt){
   if(inValidQuantity){
       showJqueryPopup();

       //Set focus to numeric text field
       jQuery('.downpaymentAmount').focus(); // This will hide the calander

      //Set the focus back to popup button
      jQuery('.ui-button').focus();

   }

}
```